# Preload images from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, image, preload

I need to preload images from my database and then show them in a slider 8 by 8.
How can I do it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                function preload(arrayOfImages) {
                $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
                $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
                // Alternatively you could use:
                // (new Image()).src = this;
    });
}
            </script>
<script>
 preload([HERE HAVE I TO DO THE SELECT FROM MY DATABASE??]);
</script>
```

The slider is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#foo1").carouFredSel({
        items               : 8,
        direction           : "left",
        width               : "100%",
        scroll : {
            items           : 1,
            easing          : "swing",
            duration        : 300
        }                   
}); 


    $("#foo1_next").click(function() {
        $("#foo1").trigger("next", 4);
    });
    $("#foo1_prev").click(function() {
        $("#foo1").trigger("prev", 4);
    });
});
</script>
```

what have I do then?

Thanks to everyone ;)

Comment: What server scripting language do you prefer?

Comment: You can't select from a server side database using pure javascript. The database code needs to be on the server side.  So it will depend on your server side language.

Comment: @JamesGaunt Well, *technically* using Node.js you could. You **can't** however do this using pure Client-Side scripting

Comment: So, Can't I do this? Only with node.js or what?

Comment: Do you use a server-side language, e.g., PHP, JSP, or ASP? What is your database?

Comment: The language is PHP and my database is MyIsam

Comment: So you need to search for how to access Mylsam from PHP and also have a look at `AJAX`

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `prefetch` link relation like so:

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="location/of/image.png" />
```

This is recommended here: http://davidwalsh.name/html5-prefetch to be used for slideshows.